# How to know if a graph contains subdivisions of $K_{3,3}$ or $K_{5}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, planar-graphs

I've been reading about planarity in graph theory and I am kind of a newbie. I know that according to Kuratowski's Theorem (1930) "a graph is planar if and only if it contains no subdivision of $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$". However, I was confused how do you actually check this? There are not very many examples online. I was thinking perhaps this could be checked with an adjacency matrix, but this sounds very tedious. Are there more efficient ways?

Comment: Google search: [algorithm for determining planarity](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C22&as_vis=1&q=algorithm+for+determining+planarity&btnG=)

Comment: Hopcroft and Tarjan showed that planarity can be tested in linear time.

Comment: It depends on what you want. Are you looking for a computational `How can I check for this algorithmically', or do you want heuristic advice on how to look at a graph and try find / rule out such a subdivision?